# Xamarin.Forms - Prism EventToCommandBehavior passing an object to a new view is converted to a string

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I've been trying the Prism framework for Xamarin.Forms lately and I've encountered an issue with EventToCommandBehavior which I am quite sure of it should work.

When I am trying to send an object from a ListView to a new view with NavigationParameters() it is automatically generated to a string instead of the object that was sent before.

As I try to cast it to an object an InvalidCastException shows up.

ListView.cs where I send the data from to a new view via Navigate():

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employeeList = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
_employeeList.Add("employee", new Employee{ Id = 1, FirstName = "FirstTest", LastName = "LastTest" });

    private async void Navigate()
    {
        var employeePara = new NavigationParameters();
        employeePara.Add("employee", _selectedEmployee);

        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("EmployeeDetail" + employeePara);
    }
```

New view, where I try to get the data as an object:

```
private Employee _employee;
public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    try
    {
if (parameters.ContainsKey("employee"))
        _employee = (Employee)parameters["employee"]; // invalid cast happening here
        EmployeeFullName = _employee.FirstName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <c:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="itemTappedEventArgs" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
      <ListView.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior
          EventName="ItemTapped"
          Command="{Binding EmployeeTappedCommand}"/>
      </ListView.Behaviors>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding FullName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prism for Forms example also uses a similar scenario, but has a different NavigateAsync method signature.
My guess, yours is wrong?

Example code `await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("RecipePage", p);`

Example solution https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/blob/master/ContosoCookbook/ContosoCookbook/ContosoCookbook/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs#L35

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into this and come back to you. Strange I've not found this example myself, been scavenging the net for hours..

Comment: Yeah I know... location of the samples is something they should be highlighting better. But I guess that with this link you'll be able to fix your problem :)

Comment: I fixed it by deleting all the external behavior/converter code and replaced it with  ItemTapped="OnItemTapped" and basically that was all I had to do to get it working. Thanks @Depechie!